# What is a Singleton Type exactly?

Tags: scala, types, singleton-type

What is a singleton type? what are the applications, the implications ?

Examples are more than welcome and layman terms are even more welcome !

Answer (score 18):

If you think of a type as a set of values, the singleton type of a value `x` is the type which only contains this value (`{x}`). Usage examples:

1. Pattern matching: `case _: Foo.type` checks that the matched object is the same as `Foo` using `eq`, where `case Foo` only checks that it's equal to `Foo` using `equals`.
2. It's needed to write down the type of an `object` (as a type parameter, an argument, etc.):

   ```
   object A
   def method(): A.type = A
   ```
3. To guarantee the return value of a method is the object it's called on (useful for method chaining, example [from here](http://scalada.blogspot.ru/2008/02/thistype-for-chaining-method-calls.html)):

   ```
   class A { def method1: this.type = { ...; this } }
   class B extends A { def method2: this.type = { ...; this } }
   ```

   You can now call `new B.method1.method2`, which you couldn't without `this.type` because `method1` would return `A`.

Comment: Perhaps you would be kind enough to give some examples as to the usefulness of this ?

Comment: @ashy_32bit I've added some examples.

Comment: "checks that the matched object is the same as `foo`" -- did you mean "the same as `Foo`"?

Comment: @VasyaNovikov Yes, fixed.

Comment: great answer, would be good to have an example for application 2. for completeness and precision

Answer (score 0):

Put it in easy words, a [singleton type](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#singleton-types) is the type of a [singleton object](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/singleton-objects.html). That object becomes the only instance of such type, and such type's purpose is to provide language consistent syntax and type checking for that single object. The reason is that singleton types are so specific that type inference does not work for them, and hence it's the developer's duty to provide type for a singleton object. In other words you should provide type declaration where the compiler shall expect a singleton object, since compiler cannot infer types in such situations:

```scala
object X
val x: X.type = X
```

Main reason for a type system to exist is to check program correctness, hence any type construct such as `X.type` shall be seen in such perspective. To understand them, ask yourself "how should you instruct compiler to accept only value of `X` (and there is only one single of such value)?" For example instead of using `X.type` in the following snippet what else could be used?

```scala
case class example(x: X.type)
```

So we could say they are there to complement the type system of a language that made it so easy to adopt OOP's [singleton pattern](https://www.baeldung.com/scala/creating-singletons): "Singleton objects effectively implement the singleton pattern in Scala with no additional effort."