# How to save a Type or TypeTag to a val for later use?

Tags: scala, generics, reflection, types

I would like to save a Type or TypeTag in a val for later use. At this time, I am having to specify a type in several locations in a block of code. I do not need to parameterize the code because only one type will be used. This is more of a curiosity than a necessity.

I tried using typeOf, classOf, getClass, and several other forms of accessing the class and type. The solution is likely simple but my knowledge of Scala typing or type references is missing this concept.

```
object Example extends App {

  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

  object TestClass { val str = "..." }
  case class TestClass() { val word = ",,," }

  def printType[A: TypeTag](): Unit = println(typeOf[A])

  printType[List[Int]]() //prints 'List[Int]'
  printType[TestClass]() //prints 'Example.TestClass'

  val typeOfCompanion: ??? = ??? //TODO what goes here?
  val typeOfCaseClass: ??? = ??? //TODO what goes here?

  printType[typeOfCompanion]() //TODO should print something like 'Example.TestClass'
  printType[typeOfCaseClass]() //TODO should print something like 'Example.TestClass'
}
```

The solution should be able to save a Type or TypeTag or what the solution is. Then, pass typeOfCompanion or typeOfCaseClass like printTypetypeOfCompanion for printing. Changing the printing portion of the code may be required; I am not certain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be more explicit here

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def printType(a: TypeTag[_]): Unit = println(a)

val typeOfCompanion = typeTag[List[Int]]

printType(typeOfCompanion)
```

Comment: That does not compile in browser or with IntelliJ for me. Also, you changed a to an argument to printType -- I am hoping for a solution that keeps it as a Type parameter because that is my use case. In browser: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/dxYttwB5RMSa83xzZHR0BQ

Comment: Type arguments can only be static. I fixed compilation error.

Comment: Type arguments can only be static. Got it. That was the concept/rule that I was missing thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
def printType[A: TypeTag](): Unit = println(typeOf[A])
```

is exactly the same as

```
def printType[A]()(implicit a: TypeTag[A]): Unit = println(typeOf[A])
```

(except for the parameter name). So it can be called as

```
val listTypeTag /* : TypeTag[List[Int]] */ = typeTag[List[Int]]

printType()(listTypeTag)
```

(you can remove the empty parameter list from `printType` if you want).

For the companion, you need to use [a singleton type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052086/what-is-a-singleton-type-exactly):

```
val companionTag = typeTag[TestClass.type]
val caseClassTag = typeTag[TestClass]
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort and explanation. I upvoted but gave the accepted answer to talex because he explained why I could not use a val in the square brackets: Type arguments can only be static.