# Unable to match a parameterized type with a concrete type after pattern-matching

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-parameter, algebraic-data-types

Using scala 2.12.8 this would not compile without a cast:

```scala
trait Content
case object A extends Content
case class B(i: Int) extends Content

def asList[C <: Content](content: C): List[C] = content match {
  case A => List(A) // compiles
  case b: B => List(b) // does not compile
}
```

```
type mismatch;
 found   : b.type (with underlying type Playground.this.B)
 required: C
```

Here's a Scastie link to the problem: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/JIziYOYNTwKoZpdCIPCvdQ

Why is working for the case object and not for the case class? How can I make it work for the case class?

#### EDIT

The first answers made me realize I oversimplified my problem, here's an updated version :

```scala
sealed trait Content
case object A extends Content
final case class B(i: Int) extends Content

sealed trait Container[+C <: Content]
case class ContainerA(content: A.type) extends Container[A.type]
case class ContainerB(content: B) extends Container[B]

object Container {
  def apply[C <: Content](content: C): Container[C] = content match {
    case A => ContainerA(A) // compiles
    case b: B => ContainerB(b) // does not compile
  }
}
```

Scastie link: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/TDlJM5SYSwGl2gmQPvKEXQ

C cannot be a subtype of B since B is final.

Comment: Replace `List(b)` with `List(content)`... but I'm not sure this method is doing what you think it's doing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> C cannot be a subtype of B since B is final.

Wrong!

[Singleton types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052086/what-is-a-singleton-type-exactly) of `B` instances are subtypes of `B`:

```
val b = B(0)
val container: Container[b.type] = Container[b.type](b)
```

Since `ContainerB` doesn't extend `Container[b.type]`, it can't be returned by the last line. And it can't be changed so that it does;

```
case class ContainerB(content: B) extends Container[content.type]
```

is not legal in Scala.

[`Null`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Null.html) is also a subtype of `B` and you can create a similar example. And so are refinement types like `B { type T = Int }`.

Other subtypes which are probably irrelevant because they don't have instances: [`Nothing`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Nothing.html), compound types like `B with Iterable[Int]`...

Comment: If we use casts as suggested by @Tim (`case b: B => ContainerB(b).asInstanceOf[Container[C]]`), we should be able to break it with a `ClassCastException`, right? Can you provide such an exampe? `Container[b.type](b)` does not break: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/YN2Wr16zSxucs5fnk8HVWg

Comment: No, because of type erasure all such casts become casts to `Container[_]` at runtime and will succeed.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is given in the comment by @lasf:

```
def asList[C <: Content](content: C): List[C] = content match {
  case A => List(A) // compiles
  case b: B => List(content) // compiles
}
```

The problem is that the return type is `List[C]` but the compiler cannot guarantee that the type of `List(b)` is `List[C]`. In particular, `C` could be a subtype of `B` in which case `List(b)` would `List[B]` which is not compatible with `List[C]`.

---

The updated version can be solved using `asInstanceOf`, though it is not pretty.

```
def apply[C <: Content](content: C): Container[C] = content match {
  case A => ContainerA(A) // compiles
  case b: B => ContainerB(b).asInstanceOf[Container[C]]
}
```

Alternatively, you could take a different approach and use implicit conversion:

```
object Container {
  implicit def contain(content: A.type): Container[A.type] = ContainerA(content)
  implicit def contain(content: B): Container[B] = ContainerB(content)
}

val ca: Container[A.type] = A
val cb: Container[B] = B(0)
```

Or even multiple constructors:

```
object Container {
  def apply(content: A.type): Container[A.type] = ContainerA(content)
  def apply(content: B): Container[B] = ContainerB(content)
}
```

---

Here is an alternative design using a [typeclass](https://blog.scalac.io/2017/04/19/typeclasses-in-scala.html). This replaces the `Content` superclass with a `Containable` typeclass. The `Container` class can now contain anything as long as there is an instance of `Containable` for that class.

```
case object A
case class B(i: Int)

sealed trait Container[C]
case class ContainerA(content: A.type) extends Container[A.type]
case class ContainerB(content: B) extends Container[B]

trait Containable[T] {
  def apply(value: T): Container[T]
}
object Containable {
  implicit object AContainer extends Containable[A.type] {
    def apply(value: A.type) = ContainerA(value)
  }
  implicit object BContainer extends Containable[B] {
    def apply(value: B) = ContainerB(value)
  }
}

object Container {
  def apply[C](content: C)(implicit containable: Containable[C]): Container[C] =
    containable(content)
}
```

Comment: Sorry I oversimplified the problem, I just edited the description. As for your answer, if I make `B` final, `C` cannot be a subtype of `B` yet it does not compile.

Comment: In fact, I'm trying to avoid those casts and the single constructor enables more code factorization by my side but maybe I'm just facing a code design issue.

Comment: @M.Karassev I think you should probably look at using [typeclasses](https://blog.scalac.io/2017/04/19/typeclasses-in-scala.html). I've added an example of how that might work.

Comment: Thanks, I actually refactored my code so I don't need those parameterized types anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are getting an error is because of the return type of the method is not explicit. On replacing the return type from List[C] to List[Content] solves the problem.

```
def asList[C <: Content](content: C): List[Content] = content match {
  case A => List(A) // compiles
  case b: B => List(b) // compiles
}
```

Comment: This makes the type parameter pointless, it might as well be `def asList(content: Content): List[Content]` and I doubt that this is what the OP wants.

Comment: If that’s the case why do we use TypeParameter C? Content is anyway the super type so we can put an object of type A and B on to the stack of Content I don’t think that’s is what the OP’s problem is.

Comment: Sorry I oversimplified the problem, I'm posting an edit asap but I still learned something from Chaitanya`s answer, thanks!