# Type pattern match why a variable is a must

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, expression, generic-programming

I am reading "Scala for Impatient 2nd" Section 14.4, where I am confused about the context :

> You can match on the type of an expression, for example :

```
obj match {
   case x:Int => x
   case s:String => Integer.parseInt(s)
   case _:BigInt => Int.MaxValue
   case _ => 0
}
```

> When you match against a type, you must supply a variable name. 
>    Otherwise, you match the object :

```
obj match {
   case _:BigInt => Int.MaxValue // Matches any object of type BigInt
   case BigInt => -1 // Matches the BigInt object of type Class
}
```

What I am confused is how to understand `obj` which is requested as an `expression` :
if I test as below :

```
val x = 121
val obj : Any = x
obj == 121 // true

obj match {
   case x:Int => x
   case s:String => Integer.parseInt(s)
   case _:BigInt => Int.MaxValue
   case _ => 0
} // res133: Int = 121
```

However if I just assign an Integer value to `obj`, compiler throws error :

```
val obj2 = 121
obj2 == 121 // true

obj2 match {
   case x:Int => x
   case s:String => Integer.parseInt(s)
   case _:BigInt => Int.MaxValue
   case _ => 0
} // <console>:22: error : scrutinee is incompatible with pattern type;
found : String
required : Int
    case s : String => Integer.parseInt(s)
             ^    
<console>:23: error : scrutinee is incompatible with pattern type;
found : BigInt
required : Int
    case _ : BigInt => Int.MaxValue
             ^
```

The only difference is the former example I assigned `obj` by another variable, while the latter example I assigned `obj` by a Integer value. Why there is a compile error for latter example ?

**Question update** : I understand that "compiler knows that `obj2` is `Int`", however, I thought that was what `match` expression works for, i,e because `obj2` is `Int` and it met the first `match` clause `case x:Int => x` thus match is successful and the whole match expression completed.  I thought this should be exactly the same as former example, the only difference is that the two variables are of `Any` and of `Int` type, but they all matched the first match clause and both of them should be compiled properly.

From this book Section 14.4 "In Scala, this (type pattern) match is preferred to using the `isInstanceOf` operator", I thought using type patterns is a way to identify object's type. If we have known the object type, what is "type pattern" used for ?

The second question is I am confused the context below. How to understand "object of type BigInt" v.s "BigInt object of type Class" ? is "type `Class`" related to java generic/reflection concept ?

```
obj match {
   case _:BigInt => Int.MaxValue // Matches any object of type BigInt
   case BigInt => -1 // Matches the BigInt object of type Class
}
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to understand "object of type BigInt" v.s "BigInt object of type Class" ? is "type Class" related to java generic/reflection concept ?

This is simply an error in the book. The `BigInt` pattern (i.e. `case BigInt => ...`) matches the [companion object](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.8/scala/math/BigInt$.html) declared as

```
object BigInt { ... }
```

in code. It is *not* of type `Class`; its type [is written as `BigInt.type`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052086/what-is-a-singleton-type-exactly), but it's quite rarely useful.

So if you write

```
val x: Any = BigInt

x match {
  case _: BigInt => // doesn't match
  case BigInt => // matches
}
```

while `val x: Any = new BigInt(...)` would match the first and not the second.

Answer (score 5):

In the second case, the compiler knows that `obj2` is `Int` and therefore it knows that it is impossible that a match for `String` or `BigInt` could succeed.

---

There is a distinction here between what is known at compile time and what is known at run time. You have the following code:

```
val x = 121
val obj: Any = x
```

At run time, both `x` and `obj` are `Int` and will match the first case in your `match` expression.

At compile time the compiler knows that `x` is `Int` so it knows that there is no point in testing for `String` or `BigInt`. All it knows about `obj` is that it is `Any` so it is OK to check for `String`, `BigInt` or any other type.

Now in this case it is clear that the compiler could work out that `obj` is actually `Int`, but this is not possible in the general case. Rather than having complex rules about type inference, the compiler just uses the type that the programmer gave to the value which is `Any`. So it assumes that `obj` could be `String` or `BigInt` even though in this case it is obvious from the code that it isn't.

Comment: Hi @Tim, thanks for quick reply. I understand that "compiler knows that `obj2` is `Int`", however, I thought that was what `match` expression works for, i,e because `obj2` is Int and it met the first `match` clause `case x:Int => x `, and the whole match expression completed.  From this book Section 14.4 "In Scala, this (type pattern) match is preferred to using the `isInstanceOf` operator", I thought using type patterns is a way to identify object's type. If we have known the object type, what is "type pattern" used for ? Thank you so much! (I also update my question accordingly).

Answer (score 1):

The second assignment is missing type ascription so due to type inference

```
val obj2 = 121
```

makes `obj2` an `Int`, as opposed to

```
val obj : Any = x
```

which made it an `Any`.