# Specifying type of a Case Object in Either

Tags: scala, singleton-type

If I have a object as follows:

```
case object Foo
```

and I try to create a value like this

```
Either[Foo, B]
```

I get a compile error saying that Foo cannot be found. But if I do this:

```
Either[Foo.type, B]
```

It compiles. My question is if this correct to do this?

Comment: Yes. Because your object `Foo` is an instance of anonymous class `Foo$` and its type is `Foo.type`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you want to declare the type of an `object` in Scala you have to declare it like `YourObject.type`.

The reason is simple, as `YourObject` is already the **instance**. So `.type` is the way you have to declare the Type of an Object (*Singleton*) in **Scala**.

Here an example:

```
object YourObject

def doit(obj: YourObject.type) = {}

def doitEventually(obj: Option[YourObject.type]) = {}


doit(YourObject)
doitEventually(Some(YourObject))
```

I couldn't find the according documentation, so maybe someone can help out with that.

The Specification is here: [singleton-types](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#singleton-types) (as mentioned by Mojo in the comments)

Comment: doc is here: https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/03-types.html#singleton-types

Comment: @Mojo thanks, I saw that, but is not really an explaination;)

Comment: [What is a Singleton Type exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33052585/5205022) might help.