# Type of user defined objects in Scala

Tags: scala, null

In Scala, Nil is actually an object which returns an empty List. When I type, Nil, it prints the following.

```
res24: scala.collection.immutable.Nil.type = List()
```

res24 is the variable whose type is `scala.collection.immutable.Nil.type`. I don't quite understand the last piece 'type'. Where this is located ?

Another question is: Nil returns an empty list. How can we write an object which returns something? I tried below; it does not return the integer value what I expected.

```
object Sample { 123 }
val x = Sample
x: Sample.type = Sample$@36fe7b03
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't quite understand the last piece 'type'. Where this is located
>   ?

This is what Scala refers to as the ["Singleton Type"](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html). `Nil` and `Sample` share the common property of being objects in Scala which entails they are classes with a single instance (given that it is a top level declaration, and not nested inside a `class`, inside a given package scope). It part of the type definition, but it isn't visible in the declaration site. For more on the uses of the singleton type see [What is a Singleton Type exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052086/what-is-a-singleton-type-exactly)

> How can we write an object which returns something?

Writing an `object` that returns something is similar to asking *"Can I create a class that returns a value when instantiated?"*. `object` are singletons and can have methods on them that returns values:

```
object Bar {
  def x(): Int = 42
}

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = print(Bar.x())
```

Which yields `42`.

## Edit

> Still I am not clear how the singleton object Nil, returning an empty
>   list

If we can simplify and mimic the `List[A]` definition, we'll see that:

```
sealed trait List[+A]
case class ::(head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]
case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
```

What we have here is an [Algebraic Data Type](https://nrinaudo.github.io/scala-best-practices/definitions/adt.html) (ADT), more specifically a Sum Type, which is a type that's composed of multiple possible values. Here, a `List[A]` can be *either* a `::`, or `Nil`, and in our case it represents the empty list case.

Comment: Still the question remains: Why does the REPL report `Nil.type = List()` instead of `Nil.type = Nil`? (That being the pattern for other `object` references.)

Comment: @yuval Itzchakov, thanks for looking into the post. Now I'm clear about the first question. Still I am not clear how the singleton object Nil, returning an empty list.

Comment: @jwvh Because the type of `object Foo` is `Foo.type` and not `Foo`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov; You've misunderstood the question. Let me try again. Define `case object Foo` in the REPL. Now reference it: `Foo`. The REPL replies `Foo.type = Foo`. OK, now reference`Nil`, which is also a case object. The REPL replies `Nil.type = List()`. Where did that `List()` business come from? It somehow picked it up because it `extends List[Nothing]`. Can `Foo` be modified to pull the same, or similar, trick?

Comment: @jwvh It comes from `toString` on `TraversableLike`: `override def toString = mkString(stringPrefix + "(", ", ", ")")`

Comment: A-ha! Dankeschön! Grazie molto!

Answer (score 1):

> In Scala, Nil is actually an object which returns an empty List.

No, Nil is an object that represents the empty list (by extending from List[Nothing]). See https://alvinalexander.com/scala/what-is-difference-between-nil-empty-list-in-scala/